# Getting an absolute path on the local file system from an IResource

Tags: java, eclipse, file

What is the better approach to get an absolute path on the local file system from an IResource?

```
IResource res;
...
res.getLocation().makeAbsolute().toString();
```

or

```
IResource res;
...
new File(res.getLocationURI()).getAbsolutePath();
```

(I skipped null checks in this example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably:

```
res.getLocation().toOSString();
```

The location should always be absolute so no need to call `makeAbsolute` (although it will not cost much when the path is already absolute).

Use `toOSString()` to get the path in the format used by the OS (so \ on Windows, / on Mac, Linux).

You can also use `toPortableString()` to get a standard format path which is useful for data interchange but is not suitable for use with `File`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see toOSString(), looks promising.